# Parse Data From text File to Hashmap

Tags: java, list, file, arraylist, hashmap

[image: Data Set]

I have a text file like the one in the image, and I want to have these data in a hashmap, which look something like this-

```
Madhya Pradesh  Bhopal
        Gwalior
        Indore
        Khandwa

Goa     Mapusa
        Margao
        Bicholim
        Panaji
```

So far, I have been able to isolate the keys and values individual Strings, but I have no idea where to go from there on. What do I need to do next?

```
while ((line=br.readLine())!=null){
    state=line.split("-")[0];
    city=line.split("-")[1];
}
```

Comment: maybe put it in a HashMap?

Comment: yes, that is what I am trying to do.. but the keys are scattered throughout.. how can I put them together? I am new to hashmap, so apologise if I don't understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already split them, just add them to a MultiMap: An implementation of MultiMap can be found in the [Apache Commons Collections](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/).

The MultiMap internally creates a collection containing all entries for a specific key. You then can get these collections if needed.

```
MultiMap stateCityMap= new MultiHashMap();
String state;
String city;
while ((line=br.readLine())!=null){
    state=line.split("-")[0];
    city=line.split("-")[1];
    stateCityMap.put(state, city);
}
```

**Edit:**

You also can do this, without any proprietary library:

```
Map<String, List<String>> stateCityMap= new HashMap<>();
String state;
String city;
while ((line=br.readLine())!=null){
    state=line.split("-")[0];
    city=line.split("-")[1];
    if(stateCityMap.get(state) == null) {
        stateCityMap.put(state, new ArrayList<String>());
    }
    stateCityMap.get(state).add(city);
}
```

Comment: is there any way I can do it without using external collections and with Java's default collection classes?

Answer (score 3):

I saw that in another question you are using Java 8. If it's the case there is a nice way to accomplish your task:

```
import static java.nio.file.Files.lines;
import static java.nio.file.Paths.get;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.mapping;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;

...

Map<String, List<String>> map = lines(get("file"))
              .map(s -> s.split("-"))
              .collect(groupingBy(arr -> arr[0], mapping(arr -> arr[1], toList())));
```

To explain a little bit what's going on:

- `Files.lines` creates a `Stream<String>` (each String is a line in the file)
- then you split each line by the dash (like you did in your while loop), that gives you a `Stream<String[]>`
- then you collect the content of the Stream by grouping the arrays with their first elements (`arr -> arr[0]`). That will give you a `Map<String, List<String[]>` <sup>1</sup>
- but you want the value mapped to be the second element of each array, so you use the `mapping` collector. Each value is then collected into a `List`, resulting in a `Map<String, List<String>>`

This is the usual idiom in Java 8, it might be a bit difficult to understand at first but once you grab the concept it's very powerful.

<sup>1. Under the hood this `Map<String, List<String[]>` is never created but it's easier to visualize it like that</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Since each key is linked to many values and not just one you should use the MultiMap interface and its MultiValueMap from Apache collections (See [here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/map/MultiValueMap.html))

Example:

```
MultiMap<String, String> myMap = new MultiValueMap<String, String>

myMap.put(state, city);
```

It will add the new value to the collection associated to that key

[EDIT] If you want to do it without using an external library you can do it the following way

```
Map<String, List<String>> myMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>)();
if myMap.containsKey(state) {
    List<String> cityList = myMap.get(state);
    cityList.add(city);
} else {
    List<String> stateCityList = new ArrayList<String>();
    stateCityList.add(city);
    myMap.put(state, stateCityList);
}
```

This would work the way you want it to.

Comment: is there any way I can do it without using external collections and with Java's default collection classes?

Answer (score 1):

You can put it into Map of List.

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
List<String> cityList;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    state = line.split("-")[0];
    city = line.split("-")[1];

    cityList = map.get(state);
    if (cityList == null) {
        cityList = new ArrayList<String>();
        map.put(state, cityList);
    }
    cityList.add(city);
}
```

Comment: Yes, exactly, i am trying to create the list of lis of cities, or values.. but to do that, i need to know which value is associated with which key.. from the file i cannot isolate that. i can only get the values one at a time

Answer (score 1):

1. First, don't split as many times as you have items: sset a variable with the result.
2. Put everything in a `Map< String, Collection<String>>` (HashMap or TreeMap which will sort the cities by state....). The first item will correspond to the key and the second will be added to the corresponding collection value.

Here is a code sample that can illustrate it :

```
Map<String, List<String> > map = new TreeMap<String, Collection<String>>();
Collection<String> cities;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] result = line.split("-");
    state = result[0];
    city = result[1];

    cities= map.get(state);
    if (cities== null) {
        cities = new ArrayList<String>();
        map.put(state, cities);
    }
    cities.add(city);
}
```